# cygwin easy_install scipy error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scipy, cygwin

I am trying to install scipy in cygwin (Win8-64) using easy_install and I have such kind of error:

```
$ easy_install scipy  
Searching for scipy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Best match: scipy 0.14.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-      0.14.0.zip#md5=7ee4fa9e756bab6b46b79f77c821cb68
Processing scipy-0.14.0.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-22pYld/scipy-0.14.0/setup.cfg
Running scipy-0.14.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-22pYld/scipy-0.14.0/egg-dist-tmp-q32R1Y
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1504: UserWarning:
Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
the ATLAS environment variable.
warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1513: UserWarning:
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
the BLAS environment variable.
warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1516: UserWarning:
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
merror:
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
the BLAS environment variable.
```

I can't figure it out by my owin what is wrong. Help will be appresiated here.

I also wonder if the successful installation of scipy will result in installation libraries for python2.7 or for python3 both of which I have in me PC (I need both)?

Any help? 
Thanks in advance!

---

After help of @abarnert:

**What I have done so far:**

- install all FORTRAN libraries via setup.exe (libgfortranlib, gcc-fortran, etc)
- pip2.7 install scipy
- pip3.2 install scipy

No problems were met during this type of installations.

Answer (score 2):

The error at the end seems pretty clear:

> error: Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

And it even tells you how to solve the error. What do you want someone here to tell you beyond that?

There may be a BLAS library as part of Cygwin's setup app. If not, go to the URL linked in the error message and download BLAS yourself.

---

Meanwhile, even though this is a completely separate question, I'll answer it:

> I also wonder if the successful installation of scipy will result in installation libraries for python2.7 or for python3 both of which I have in me PC (I need both)?

It depends on which `easy_install` you're running. The simplest thing to do is not try to guess or figure it out, just explicitly use `easy_install-2.7` and `easy_install-3.4` (or whichever version).

However, you probably shouldn't be using `easy_install` in the first place. Use `pip` instead unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, as recommended by both the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html) and the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html).